# Using an existing Enum in new Alembic migration in python

Tags: python, database, postgresql, alembic

I've created Enum for one model in first migration:

```
def upgrade() -> None:
    …
    gender_enum = postgresql.ENUM('MALE', 'FEMALE', 'OTHER', name='genderenum', create_type=False)
    gender_enum.create(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=True)
    op.add_column('user', sa.Column('gender', gender_enum, nullable=True))
    …

def downgrade() -> None:
    …
    gender_enum = sa.Enum(name='genderenum')
    gender_enum.drop(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=True)
    …
```

How can I use this Enum with other model in new migration? I don't need to create new one.
I've tried to create new one with «checkfirst», but it just hasn't created.

And one more question: I used `create_type=False`, but type was created in db. Is it ok, what is this arg for?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:

```
    sql = '''
    ALTER TABLE new_user_table
    ADD COLUMN gender genderenum;
    '''
    op.execute(sql)
```